# New Object from objects

Tags: python, oop, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to implement Genetic Algorithm and I am new to python and i am trying to build a Python class Gene with the following as properties

```
Gene has Portid,trt,days
```

And a second class Chromosome with 20 Gene objects as its property

```
Chromosome has gene1,gene2,gene3...gene20
```

As shown in this diagram [UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/redp8.png) Any help please

I have tried

```
import random
class Gene:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id=id
        self.nb_trax=random.randint(1,10)
        self.nb_days=random.randint(50,100)

class Chromosome(object):
    def __init__(self,object):
        self.port[i] = [Gene(id) for i in range (20)]
g=Gene('China')
f=Chromosome(g)
```

and i get an error

```
f=Chromosome(g)
  File "chrom.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.port[i] = [Gene(id) for i in range (20)]
AttributeError: 'Chromosome' object has no attribute 'port'
```

Comment: Looks like an assignment copied almost verbatim... What have you tried yourself?

Comment: If you're trying, what did you already achieve?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  i have added code i tried

Comment: Python version?

Comment: @Adirio  python 3.4

Comment: @Alex.S I have added my code

Comment: So, what the problem now? What would be your question?

Comment: @Alex.S i get this error ` f=Chromosome(g)
  File "chrom.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.port[i] = [Gene(id) for i in range (20)]
AttributeError: 'Chromosome' object has no attribute 'port'
`

Comment: Put that error into the question and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Alex.S Noted and corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. Python 3 does not need `(object)` hierarchy for classes. You were also using it as a parameter that you were not using so I also deleted it from there. And the part inside the square bracke3ts `[]` laready creates the list so you don't need to assign it to `self.port[i]` but to `self.port` directly.

```
import random

class Gene:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.nb_trax = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.nb_days = random.randint(50, 100)

class Chromosome:
    def __init__(self):
        self.port = [Gene(id) for id in range(20)]
```